# Limit comparison test vs quotient test

Tags: sequences-and-series

My lecturer talks of a 'Quotient Test':

Let
$$s=\sum_{n=0}^∞ a_n, S=\sum_{n=0}^∞ b_n$$
Consider $$p=\lim_{n\to ∞}(\frac{a_n}{b_n})$$
If

1. $$0\leq p<∞$$ and S converges, then s converges.
2. $$p=∞$$ and s converges, then S converges.

I've also encountered a 'Limit Comparison Test' online, which states that if $$0<p<∞$$, then either both S and s converge, or both S and s diverge.

Are these both valid tests of convergence?

Comment: These are all valid, and not too difficult to prove.

Comment: Sounds like this "quotient test" is just the same thing as the limit comparison test, but also with the special cases at $p=0$ and $p=\infty$.